# Connect to FTP server

Tags: ftp

I am creating FTP by android(from default file manager app) and am trying to connect it on my ubuntu. In file manager I tried to do

> connect to server

but when i click connect, it is showing this error.

> Error resolving "address..": name or service not known

I am on the same wifi network on both android and ubuntu. how to solve this?

Comment: What is the exact url string you entered at the file manager? (you don't have to share the the real ip addresses or dns names).
Are you able to connect using the terminal / other ftp supported applications? Also: what ubuntu version are you currently using?

Comment: url: ftp:// and then address like xx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx and I am new to ubuntu and don't know how to connect using terminal and I am using ubuntu version 18.04.4

Comment: Simply open the terminal and type: ftp x.x.x.x, or ftp your_domain_name. also add "user@" before the ip or domain if it is user protected. See if you can reach the server.

Comment: There was a problem with my android application. I changed it to create FTP and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear! I will convert this comment to an answer and you may mark it as accepted so it will no longer appear as "unanswered" for people searching such questions to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the output error you presented, it seems like you were unable to connect your remote FTP server from some reason.

For more detailed responses I would suggest also to try connecting using the terminal, as you can actually see the process of the client request and response from the server.
This will also help understand if the problem is the usage of the file manager or the connection itself.

Simply open the terminal and type: `ftp your_server_IP_address` , or `ftp your_server_domain_name` . Also add `user@` before the ip or domain if it is user protected.

If you get an error about being unable to resolve the target name or IP, you might have a network problem or the connection is being blocked from some reason.